# Bug in DateTime.ToString("T") and DateTime.ToString("G")?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

[Microsoft specifies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings?redirectedfrom=MSDN) `:` as `The time separator`, but it seems there are at least two time separators: one between hours and minutes and another one between minutes and seconds.

[image: Long time format settings in control panel]
<sub>(source: [wellisolutions.de](http://uploads.wellisolutions.de/stackoverflow/ControlPanelLongTimeFormat.png))</sub>

[image: Long time format shown by Windows clock]
<sub>(source: [wellisolutions.de](http://uploads.wellisolutions.de/stackoverflow/ClockCustomFormat.png))</sub>

Is there a way to get the specific time separators? I need the one between hours and minutes and the other one between minutes and seconds.

I would also not mind building my DateTime string in other ways, e.g. using the [standard format string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings?redirectedfrom=MSDN) `T` or `G`, but they both don't work

```
mydate.ToString("T");
// Output: 20-29-46
// Expected output: 20-29:46 (as shown by Windows clock)

mydate.ToString("G");
// Output: 09/03-2014 20-29-46
// Expected output: 09/03-2014 20-29:46
```

Comment: That might be worth filing a report on connect.microsoft.com, I would expect the standard format strings to follow the OS setting.

Comment: Given that the built-in mechanism for formatting doesn't seem to work as expected, in a worst-case scenario you can always call down to the underlying OS API yourself using interop to perform the correct formatting.

Comment: I can hear a Microsoft programmer scream at that bug report.

Comment: Did you try to check the currentculture and look into the datetimeformat?
            `CultureInfo c2 = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;`

            `Console.WriteLine(c2.DateTimeFormat.ToString());`
You will see the property "LongTimePattern". Then maybe you can check with a regexp to extract the separators...

Comment: I can't even get `DateTimeFormat`'s short time pattern to change by changing the Windows settings...

Comment: @Rawling Interesting; that works for me. I go to "Region", "Formats" and click button "Additional settings...". Then I get the window from the screenshot above, on tabs "Time" and "Date" (or German "Uhrzeit", "Datum"). I can type in sick formats (not just choose from the suggested formats). This works in .NET. My process runs as the same user that changed the OS settings, I think. I did not change my `CultureInfo` in the .NET application. Already `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.UseUserOverride` is true. This can depend on OS and OS version, of course.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Control Panel Region and Language setting let you set arbitrary many separators and arguments, but .net CultureInfo DateTimeFormat just assume the user is sane. So even a roundtrip like DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString()) won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Getting separators**

As stated by Jeppe Stig Nielson (maybe upvote for him), there is no good way to get the second time or date separator, because in a format string like

```
HH-mm/HH:mm-HH/mm
```

there can be multiple of them, even with the same semantics (e.g. between hours and minutes).

**Microsoft bug report**

I have registered at Microsoft Connect and filed the bug as [DateTime.ToString("T") and DateTime.ToString("G")](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/832306/datetime-tostring-t-and-datetime-tostring-g). If you have a Microsoft Connect account, you can vote whether or not you can reproduce the bug.

**SSCCE to reproduce the bug**

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

namespace DateTimeToString
{
    class Program
    {
        // Tested on
        // Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise x64 Version 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Build 7601
        // I should have all official updates installed at the time of writing (2014-03-11)
        //
        // Microsoft Visual Studio Premium 2012 Version 11.0.61030.00 Update 4
        // Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.5.50938
        //
        // Type: Console application x86
        // Target framework: .NET 4 Client Profile
        static void Main()
        {
            if (DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.LongTimePattern != "HH-mm:ss" ||
                DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.ShortDatePattern != "dd.MM/yyyy")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Configure long time format to MM-mm:ss to reproduce the time bug.");
                Console.WriteLine("Configure short date format to dd.MM/yyyy to reproduce the date bug.");
                Console.WriteLine("Control Panel/Region and Language/Additional settings");
                return;
            }

            var dateTime = DateTime.Now;
            Console.WriteLine("Expected: " + dateTime.ToString("HH'-'mm':'ss"));
            Console.WriteLine("Actual  : " + dateTime.ToString("T"));
            Console.WriteLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Expected: " + dateTime.ToString("dd'.'MM'/'yyyy HH'-'mm':'ss"));
            Console.WriteLine("Actual  : " + dateTime.ToString("G"));
            Console.WriteLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Expected: " + dateTime.ToString("HH'-'mm':'ss"));
            Console.WriteLine("Actual  : " + dateTime.ToLongTimeString());
            Console.WriteLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Expected: " + dateTime.ToString("dd'.'MM'/'yyyy"));
            Console.WriteLine("Actual  : " + dateTime.ToShortDateString());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

**Workaround**

As a workaround, we can use the native methods [GetTimeFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318130%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [GetDateFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318086%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var systemTime = new SystemTime(DateTime.Now);

        Console.WriteLine("ShortDatePattern (as reported by .NET): " + DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.ShortDatePattern);
        var sbDate = new StringBuilder();
        GetDateFormat(0, 0, ref systemTime, null, sbDate, sbDate.Capacity);
        Console.WriteLine("Date string (as reported by kernel32) : " + sbDate);
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.WriteLine("LongTimePattern (as reported by .NET) : " + DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.LongTimePattern);
        var sbTime = new StringBuilder();
        GetTimeFormat(0, 0, ref systemTime, null, sbTime, sbTime.Capacity);
        Console.WriteLine("Time string (as reported by kernel32) : " + sbTime);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern int GetDateFormat(int locale, uint dwFlags, ref SystemTime sysTime,
        string lpFormat, StringBuilder lpDateStr, int cchDate);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern int GetTimeFormat(uint locale, uint dwFlags, ref SystemTime time, 
        string format, StringBuilder sb, int sbSize);


    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct SystemTime
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)] private readonly ushort Year;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)] private readonly ushort Month;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)] private readonly ushort DayOfWeek;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)] private readonly ushort Day;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)] private readonly ushort Hour;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)] private readonly ushort Minute;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)] private readonly ushort Second;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)] private readonly ushort Milliseconds;

        public SystemTime(DateTime dateTime)
        {
            Year = (ushort) dateTime.Year;
            Month = (ushort) dateTime.Month;
            DayOfWeek = (ushort) dateTime.DayOfWeek;
            Day = (ushort) dateTime.Day;
            Hour = (ushort) dateTime.Hour;
            Minute = (ushort) dateTime.Minute;
            Second = (ushort) dateTime.Second;
            Milliseconds = (ushort) dateTime.Millisecond;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just set the formats in .NET as you like. For example:

```
var clonedProvider = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone();

clonedProvider.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern = "HH-mm':'ss";
clonedProvider.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd'/'MM-yyyy";
```

Then:

```
mydate.ToString("T", clonedProvider);
mydate.ToString("G", clonedProvider);
```

Note that I put the colon `:` and the slash `/` into single quotes (apostrophes `'`) to prevent them from being translated into whatever separator your culture has from the outset. I just want literal colon and slash.

If you don't want to write `clonedProvider` everywhere, change the culture permanently on your current thread:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.ReadOnly(clonedProvider);
```

Do you have many threads in your application?

---

**Edit** after comment:

If you want to see how the OS settings has affected your .NET format provider object, just inspect the strings:

```
DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.ShortDatePattern
DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.LongTimePattern
```

and so on. I suppose your current format provider has `UseUserOverride` set to `true`, so the user settings from Windows will be visible.

There is no limit to the number of "separators" the user could have typed in. For example someone might use `"ddd;dd-MM,yyyy"`. So there are *three* separators there. So you will have to examine the string yourself to see how many "separators" and "components" are there, and which characters the user uses as separator in each place.

---

Reading your question carefully, and relating to your example, I see that you typed `HH-mm:ss` in the Windows setting. That has got a problem with it. When translated to .NET syntax, the first separator `-` becomes ***the*** time separator. Then the next separator, the colon, in .NET is a "wildcard" meaning "substitute with time separator". So that colon is translated to a dash as well.

You should have typed, in Windows settings,

```
HH-mm':'ss
```

where again you *protect* the colon with single quotes (apostrophes).

Now what if one of your users uses a non-standard separator first, and then later uses the standard separator `:` (or `/`) without quoting the latter in single quotes? Well, in that case you are right, there is a difference between the behavior in Windows and that in .NET. Apparently users should not type formats like that. *You could call this a bug.*

Comment: This isn't really `a way to get the specific time separators` as specified in the Windows time settings.

Comment: I don't want to compile my code for each single customer just to reflect his OS settings.

Comment: @Rawling Maybe I misunderstood. See my edit. There is no guarantee the number of separators is two. There could be zero, one or three separators in the string, for example. So you should examine the string yourself. Some sick person could use `d.yyyy`, so only day-of-month and year, but no month number. Don't make assumptions when you rely on user settings.

Comment: @ThomasW. Please see my final edit. The colon `:` character is special in .NET. You should use `':'`, with single quotes `'`, to prevent that special interpretation of colon.

Comment: +1 for the point about multiple separators. I think this even answers the only question I have written: there's no way to get "**the** second separator", because there could be multiple of them.

Comment: "You should have typed, in Windows settings,...where again you protect the colon".  No.  The .NET formatter rules do not change the encoding used by Windows.  It is up to .NET to properly escape strings obtained from the registry, in order to not change their meaning.  When you type `HH-mm:ss` in the Windows control panel, then `DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.LongTimePattern` should evaluate to `HH-mm':'ss`.

Comment: @BenVoigt I understand your "opinion". I don't know whose responsibility this is. If you are right, certainly my last statement should be strengthened to *this is clearly a bug*.