# Compare different date format

Tags: c#, blazor, webassembly

I am doing a search by date. Even though below dates are Same, they wouldn't return true, as the time from Json is different from the time returned by datetimepicker.

I want to compare only by date, not the time.
Below should be true:

Date selected by user -> 2022-11-26T00:00:00
Date I get from Json  -> 26.11.2022 12:42:09

How can I compare this and return true. Thank you.

```
 private DateTime dateSelectedByUser = DateTime.Today;
 public async Task DateOnChange(ChangeEventArgs args)
{
    var value = args.Value.ToString();
    dateSelectedByUser = value == string.Empty ? DateTime.Today : DateTime.Parse(value);
    result = items.Where(item=> item.date == dateSelectedByUser ).ToArray();
 }
```

Thank you.

Comment: `Value.ToString();` <-- Here's your problem. This will use `CurrentCulture` which is request-specific rather than invariant. Instead always specify an explicit format. I don't recommend using `InvariantCulture` specifically as it uses US date formats instead of ISO 8601, but it's straightforward to make your own `CultureInfo` that's ISO 8601-compliant.

Comment: Another approach is to avoid JSON string representations of `DateTime` values entirely and use `Int64` integer Unix time values, which is reliable and machine-portable, if not directly human-readable.

Comment: `DateTime.Today` <-- Do you have a good reason for not using UTC?

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question...

Comment: args.Value is the value that comes from datetimepicker. It is DateTime.

Comment: Actually, args.Value is of type "string" (at least on my test with Wasm .net 6). What is the content of "items" ? And what is the format of "dateFromJson" from your item class ?

Comment: DateTime can come in 3 kinds: UTC, Local and Unspecified - and is buggy! So try to use DateTimeOffset instead of DateTime as soon as possible by converting it to it. And parse the strings with a format pattern (is the json format always the same - looks like European) - and attention: [dots in format pattern could be / with en-US culture (or was it vice-versa)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22297803/593045)!

Comment: @Julien Please see the edited, I get as string from Json and then change to DateTime format.

Comment: And you want the "result" variable to contain data for a specific date (a whole day), or a specific DateTime (up to the second) ?

Comment: Date alone need to be compared between both. Like 26.11.2022.

Comment: Then read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.date?view=net-7.0 or better https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.date?view=net-6.0

Comment: I would agree with the answer posted by MrC aka Shaun Curtis. For your implementation, I would combine DateOnly and on your where clause, I would use the Datetime.Date to be able to make an equal between the two. Remove any serialization, and only use objects

Comment: Thank you everyone. I will check and get back on this.

Comment: As quick fix `DateOnly.FromDateTime(datetime instance)` should work within the same time zone! https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dateonly.fromdatetime?view=net-7.0#system-dateonly-fromdatetime(system-datetime)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I compare this and return true

How to handle DateTime is a really nasty interview question.  It will catch most programmers out.

Let's look at your code.

Your input type is set to `date` i.e. date without time, but your datatype is set to `DateTime`.  Though you get no errors or warnings, in reality you've crossed a type error boundary.   If you store `date1` now and `date2` now, `date1 ==  date2` will always return false.  Unless you stored them at precisely the same point  in time (which is impossible on the same machine), they will be different.

There's some modern C# (and database) coding rules to follow:

1. If you're only interested in date use the `DateOnly` type.
2. Otherwise use `DateTimeOffset`.

Though I'm sure I'll get comments from those who disagree, all the other TimeDate stuff is to maintain backwards compatibility with old C# which was too simplistic with date time!

Here's a simple Demo page based on the code you provided.  There's no indication where a json date fits in so that's `DateFromSomewhereElse`.

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<input class="form-control mb-3" type="date" @bind-value=this.MyDate />

<div class="@this.AlertCss"> Dates Are the Same: @this.DatesAreSame </div >

@code {
    private DateOnly MyDate = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now);

    private DateTime DateFromSomewhereElse = DateTime.Now;

    private bool DatesAreSame => MyDate == DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateFromSomewhereElse);

    private string AlertCss => this.DatesAreSame
        ? "alert alert-success"
        : "alert alert-danger";

}
```

##### For those pre C#10:

Create extension methods for DateTime and DateTimeOffset to get the midnight values:

```
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    public static DateTime AsDateOnly(this DateTime value) 
        => new DateTime(value.Year, value.Month, value.Day);

    public static DateTime AsDateOnly(this DateTimeOffset value)
        => new DateTime(value.Year, value.Month, value.Day);
}
```

And then the test page:

```
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<input class="form-control mb-3" type="date" @bind-value=this.MyDate />

<div class="@this.AlertCss"> Dates Are the Same: @this.DatesAreSame </div >

@code {
    private DateTimeOffset MyDate = DateTimeOffset.Now;

    private DateTimeOffset DateFromSomewhereElse = DateTimeOffset.Now;

    private bool DatesAreSame => MyDate.AsDateOnly() == DateFromSomewhereElse.AsDateOnly();

    private string AlertCss => this.DatesAreSame
        ? "alert alert-success"
        : "alert alert-danger";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will check on this as well.

Comment: Sorry I am still not able to get my head around. This is the value returned from the above query 2022-11-17T10:15:30+03:00 . This is the value from returned from DateTime picker 2022-11-17T00:00:00. I want to compare both and return true (as both have same date). Do I set DateOnly  or DateTimeOffset on dateSelectedByUser ? Can you point where do I need to use exactly. Thank you.

Comment: See my updated answer for some demo code.

Comment: Thanks again. DateOnly and TimeOnly seem to be available only in .NET 6. Using .NET 5

Comment: That was a late bit of vital info to reveal!  See my revised answer using extension methods to get the midnight versions of `DataTime` and `DateTimeOffset`.

Comment: Above query converts Json string(date) to nullable DateTime format. When I try this line: items.Where(item=> item.date.AsDateOnly() == dateSelectedByUser.AsDateOnly()). Says DateTime? does not contain definition for AsDateOnly(). I couldn't succeed in converting nullable DateTime to DateTimeOffset. Which I believe has to be done in the query itself.

Comment: You have the pattern above for creating an extension.  Create one for `DateTime?`, which is a nullable DateTime..